# How to open application instead of context menu in gnome notification area?

Tags: gnome, menu

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 and GNOME (gnome-session 3.9.90). When i clicking on icon in the notification area, I see a context menu, not the window of application (early my Skype and Dropbox opens a window, not the menu).

How can I fix it (open app window, not menu)?

[image: Screen-shot showing menu of Skype being opened instead of Skype]