# Left button click on tray icons open context menu instead of opening the app

Tags: system-tray

Every time I left click the tray icon of an app, it opens the context menu instead of opening the app itself.

I'm using Ubuntu in a virtual machine since I faced this issue on Ubuntu Budgie, I wanted to be sure it's not Budgie related. It seems to be Ubuntu related.

Example apps: Spotify, Steam, Telegram. Also NVidia panel on Ubuntu Budgie.

So I think we can say this occurs with every kind of app.

I found some issues related to that on Electron repository, but I don't think all the above apps are made on Electron, so it's most likely a issue with Ubuntu itself (https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/14941).

Related questions that weren't answered yet:

- [Open application after tray icon click or double-click instead of menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1453424/open-application-after-tray-icon-click-or-double-click-instead-of-menu)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 systray icons open menu on left click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514766/ubuntu-14-04-systray-icons-open-menu-on-left-click)
- [ubuntu : right click is acting as left click on context menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988513/ubuntu-right-click-is-acting-as-left-click-on-context-menu)
- [How to open application instead of context menu in gnome notification area?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487110/how-to-open-application-instead-of-context-menu-in-gnome-notification-area)

> OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
> Host: VirtualBox 1.2
> Kernel: 6.5.0-25-generic
> Uptime: 12 mins
> Packages: 1572 (dpkg), 9 (snap)
> Shell: bash 5.1.16
> Resolution: 1280x800
> DE: GNOME 42.9
> WM: Mutter
> WM Theme: Adwaita
> Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
> Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
> Terminal: gnome-terminal
> CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics (1) @ 3.193GHz
> GPU: 00:02.0 VMware SVGA II Adapter
> Memory: 1152MiB / 3907MiB